# Nginx + Ruby - Adding multiple domains makes the app inaccessible?

Tags: ruby, nginx

I'm at my wits end. I have this rather plain app with this in nginx.conf, and I can access it just fine on my local network.

```
http {
...

server {
listen 80;
server_name something.local;
passenger_enabled on;
root /home/user/testapp/public;
}

...
}
```

However adding another domain to that makes the entire thing inaccessible, even the local domain no longer works.

```
http {
...

server {
listen 80;
server_name something.local something.mydomain.com;
passenger_enabled on;
root /home/user/testapp/public;
}

...
}
```

Any ideas? Is it the app, is it nginx?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your reverse proxy setup.

Comment: In nginx I have nothing configured to that end, just the default nginx.conf with this in it. Server is behind a rounter which routes something.mydomain.com:3000 from the Internet to 192.168.10.15:80 which is this nginx machine. When checking something.local I'm inside the lan with the nginx machine. When connecting to something.mydomain.com:3000 and expecting to see what I get on something.local I'm somewhere on the internet.

Comment: This can also be a memory issue. Try analysing the app that uses more memory and probably tweak nginx's worker processes.

Comment: @KarthikK Hmm, this is new. I'm on a VPS with 1GB of ram. What exactly can I tweak, give me a keyword and I'll google, never done this before.